# How to pass parameters down the dependency chain using Ninject

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ninject

My Class Structure is:

```
public class PhotoService {

    private IRepository _repo;
    private DTConfig _config;

    public PhotoService(IRepository repo, DTConfig config)
    {    

        _repo = repo;
        _config = config;
    }
}

public class DTConfig
{
     private int _accountId;
     public DTConfig(int accountId)
     {
           _accountId = accountId;
     }
}
```

My Ninject Bindings are like:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IPhotoService>().To<PhotoService>();
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
kernel.Bind<DTConfig>().ToSelf();
```

Now what I want, is to pass the `accountId` as a parameter while creating an instance of **PhotoService**

```
var photo = kernel.Get<IPhotoService>();
```

How can I pass the parameter to DTConfig while creating an instance of PhotoService. The accountId is fetched from a service and is not available in compile time.

Feel free to comment if any other information is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yannick's answer is a good, however, here's an alternative: create an `IAccountService` that has the logic to find and return the AccountId. Then inject that service into your `IPhotoService`.

Answer (score 6):

There's the concept of a `ConstructorArgument` in Ninject, which allows you to pass through variables only known at runtime. The typical example of this would be:

```
var photoService = kernel.Get<IPhotoService>(new ConstructorArgument("accountId", <your value here>));
```

Now the caveat with this is that this only goes **one** level deep. There is however a contructor that accepts a bool flag called `shouldInherit`, which allows your values to propagate to the children when resolving the concrete types:

```
var photoService  = kernel.Get<IPhotoService>(new ConstructorArgument("accountId", <your value here>, shouldInherit:true));
```

Answer (score 4):

While I have found that it is overkill in some situations, using a factory will help provide constructor-like features while preserving the style of writing for injection. This is provided by the `Ninject.Extensions.Factory` [extension](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory).

At a basic level, you create a factory interface which has a matching subset of the constructor arguments. It can both resolve bound components, and require input itself. Here is a slightly modified example from the [wiki](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface);

```
public class Foo
{
    readonly IBarFactory barFactory;

    public Foo(IBarFactory barFactory)
    {
        this.barFactory = barFactory;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        var bar = this.barFactory.CreateBar("doodad");
        //Do Foo things
        bar.Stuff();
    }
}

public interface IBarFactory
{
    IBar CreateBar(string someParameter);
}
public interface IBar
{
    void Stuff();
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public Bar(IDependancy aDependancy, string someParameter)
    {
        //Initialise Object
    }
    public void Stuff()
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Then by binding a factory with;

```
_kernel.Bind<IBarFactory>().ToFactory();
```

the extension will do some magic behind the scenes.

In this example, assuming `IDependancy` is bound correctly, calling the `CreateBar` method of the factory will resolve any dependancies in parallel with inserting your parameter.

One word of caution, however, is that the parameter names need to be the same.